# Is there a way to call Variables file multiple times with different arguments and have it override the previous call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automated-tests, robotframework

I want to create a Robot Keywords file for deploying different pods to Kubernetes. The configuration is chosen based on a parameter passed when calling the keyword from the test file. I created a custom python class to handle deployment. The class takes as parameters a config dictionary generated by "get_variables" function based on the parameters passed. I want to instantiate three objects of the class with 3 different config files generated by get_variables. However when I call get variables multiple times, the configuration is NOT overridden. It remains the same.
Here's an example to further explain:

```
Variables  ../etc/get_test_config.py    ${arg1}     ${arg2}     ${arg3}
Library     k8s.K8s    ${config}    WITH NAME    frontend

Variables  ../etc/get_test_config.py    ${arg4}     ${arg5}     ${arg6}
Library     k8s.K8s    ${config}    WITH NAME    backend
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can use the keyword [Import Variables](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Variables).